# download apache server config

Tags: ftp, download, debian

How to config apache2 for download server (any file in webroot download by link ) ?
No one can build a security problem with file upload and execute file upload ? (limit my user for upload Problematic files)
‌Best Regards.

Comment: Which version _exactly_ of apache are you using?

Comment: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The download part is easy, simply put your file in the directory you want under Apache's document root which is specified in the Apache configuration file. Then you should be able merely use a link to allow people to download it.

The upload part is much harder. You need to decide which technology you want to use, Apache supports WebDAV for example, but you've specified you want to use ftp. I would recommend using a ftp server like vsftpd if you want to use ftp because you can use its features to lock down you upload directory to prevent "problematic" files.